# MediaList play items with run time option

Tags: vlcj

I use the MediaList to play some movies and streams in a list.

```
String[] paths = { "\tmp\movie1.mp4", "\tmp\movie2.mp4", "http://stream.mp4" };
String[] options = { "--run-time=2", "--run-time=5", "--run-time=10" };
```

The initialization of the media list is as follows

```
mediaListPlayer = factory.newMediaListPlayer();                    
mediaListPlayer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

MediaList mediaList = factory.newMediaList();                    
for ( int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++ ) 
{
    if ( options[i].length() > 0 )
    {
        mediaList.addMedia(paths[i], options[i]);
    }
    else
    {
         mediaList.addMedia(paths[i]);                            
    }
}
mediaListPlayer.setMediaList(mediaList);
mediaListPlayer.setMode(MediaListPlayerMode.LOOP);
mediaListPlayer.play();
```

The media list player ignores the optons. What is wrong with the code? Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the options is not obvious, this works:

```
:start-time=30
:run-time=5
```

The above options would start at 30 seconds, (you can use e.g. 30.5 for fractions of a second), and run for 5 seconds.

So replace your "--run-time=5" with ":run-time=5".

Comment: Yes it works. Is the : only for MediaList options? What about the prefix for libvlc arguments, is it still --?

Many thanks

Comment: I never found definitive documentation for that anywhere, but those "--" switches work for the media player factory, everywhere else as far as I know should use the colon syntax.